# Why aren't there line breaks in this <pre> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, pubnub, highlightjs

I'm using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) to display some JSON I'm receiving from a [pubnub](/questions/tagged/pubnub) subscription.  It is coloring the text but it is not adding line breaks as expected (via [their demos](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/)).  Also, a couple places in the documentation give the impression that the library generates new lines.  See the `useBR` option [here](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#configure-options).

Here is my current code (I've tried a few different things):

```
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel : 'TEST',
    message : function(m){
        console.log(m);
        var hlt = hljs.highlight('json',m);
        $('#jsonOutput').html("<pre>" + hlt.value + "</pre>");
    }
});
```

And here is what the DOM looks like:

[image]

But here is the output:

[image]

How can I get line breaks?  I want it to look similar to this:

```
{
    "id":"TESTWIDGET1",
    "value":371,
    "timestamp":"2016-08-31T11:39:57.8733485-05:00"
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vgfnod58/

Comment: `spans` have are by default inline elements. If you want line breaks you need to add them either by adding <br /> or using block level elements.

Comment: Can you create stacksnippets or jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: It's possible that highlight.js isn't responsible for adding newlines (just syntax highlighting) and pubnub doesn't return json with newlines. You might have to parse it and add the newlines yourself.

Comment: @Andrew Good thought, but there are references in the API that lead me to believe that's not the case: http://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fixmarkup-value

Comment: It looks like that function replaces newlines with `<br>` but that won't do anything if it doesn't have newlines in the first place. I'm just guessing though.

Comment: Check the `useBR` option, it says `generate <br> tags instead of new-line characters in the output` which implies to me that it "generates new-line characters".  I don't know though.

Comment: It is simple: you don't have line-breaks. What you see there is generate from Chrome. Right-Click the parent element and click on "edit as HTML" then you will see, that you don't have any breaks

Comment: I understand that, but my impression from the highlight.js docs is that *it* generates new lines.  see: http://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#configure-options

Comment: Yes, but it will only replace tabs when they are in the original json-string. Just have a look at my answer in a few moments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any line-breaks in your code.  The highlight function will only apply the formatting options, when the json-string was formatted. You string is only one single line. So, you will have to bring it in the right format first and then you can highlight it:

```
function print_r(object,html){
    if(html) return '<pre>' +  JSON.stringify(object, null, 4) + '</pre>';
    else return JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
}  

var m = {"id":"TESTWIDGET1","value":351,"timestamp":"2016-08-31T12:03:24.3403952-05:00"};
var hlt = hljs.highlight('json',print_r(m));
$('#codehere').html(hlt.value);
```

Please be aware that I changed the var `m` from string to object (just remove the sourrunding `'`).

A working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WalterIT/vgfnod58/2/

Comment: I simplified it and replaced `var hlt = ...` with `var hlt = hljs.highlight('json',JSON.stringify($.parseJSON(m), null, 4));` and it seems to work fine in my code.

Comment: Glad to hear. When you are using it oftener, you should make a function for it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to substitute using `<div>` element with `css` `white-space` set to `pre` for `<pre>` element

---

Edit, Updated

Alternative approach inserting non-breaking space and newline characters before and after highlighted `<span>` elements

```
var m = '{"id":"TESTWIDGET1","value":351,"timestamp":"2016-08-31T12:03:24.3403952-05:00"}';
// hljs.configure({useBR: true});
var hlt = hljs.highlight('json',m);
$('#codehere').html(hlt.value)
$('#codehere span').each(function(i) {
if (i % 2 === 0)
  $(this).before("\n&nbsp;&nbsp;");
if (i === $('#codehere span').length -1)
  $(this).after("\n")
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vgfnod58/3/

Comment: @Scott _"This did not work."_ Can you create a stacksnippet or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate? Note, at demo at `highlight.js` documentation, `<pre>` element has `<code>` element as first child https://highlightjs.org/usage/